# When was Intel's GMA3100 released?

Tags: graphics-card

The [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA) page on GMA annoyingly doesn't have full timeline data and I can't find it on Google/Intel either. Our customer is wanting our app to work on graphics released after a certain date and since the 3100 is a low-spec card I want to try and check which side of the line it falls.

Comment: The Wiki Page (linked directly from the one in your post) for Intel's chipsets does have release dates in most cases and it lists May 2007 as the release date for the chipsets that supported the GMA X3100.

Comment: I think this might be a better fit on superuser. As a point of interest though, if you're talking about app support then the date when it was last generally available might be as (more?) useful than the first available date when it comes to determining how many of these are likely to be in the wild. IIRC it was a mid to late generation core2duo motherboard component, and possibly the atom too.

Comment: @Helvick the 3100 and the X3100 are totally different products

Comment: @Robert this is less about what's sensible and more about complying with pre-agreed clauses :(

Comment: I understand how that works but I figured it was best to give you any ideas I thought might help and let you line it up how you please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intel G33 Performance Review](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2339) from 2007 refers to it as :

> mid-year release known as the G33, aka
>   the GMA 3100

So this dates from mid-2007.

Answer (score 1):

GMA 3100 is part of the G31 chipset also, according to Intel
http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/chipsets/p31/p31-overview.htm

The G31 chipset Data sheet is dated July 2007
http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/317495.pdf